# Why does my Internal Test Track opt-in URL not work?

Tags: url, testing, hyperlink, google-play

I'm developing an app and am ready to release it to a small group (5) of testers for internal testing, so I added their Gmail addresses to the list:

[image]

I sent one of the testers the link to the app and after opening email and selecting the link, they got this:

[image]

followed by this:

[image]

So far, so good. Now when I select the tester in question, instead of advancing to the next page, which is the start of a tutorial (as the app does when it's run from Android Studio), it returns to the previous screen. No error message or crash (I checked with Crashlytics). Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

**UPDATE:** I added Firebase event logging to my app and saw that no events are being logged from the LoginActivity (on the other hand, when I install the app via Android Studio, events DO get logged). Logcat shows a NameNotFoundException thrown by the PackageManager for for the app's package. Thinking the package manager doesn't like app bundles, I generated an APK instead, but got the same problem.

**UPDATE #2:** The next thing I tried was re-installing the app via Android Studio. When I simply let the app run, it exhibited the same problem, but if I ran it in Debug mode, it was fine. Not a solution, just a clue.

If I don't get this resolved by this weekend, I'll have to email my testers the APK. I wish someone in the Firebase group were monitoring this problem because emailing APKs as a workaround really sucks!

**UPDATE #3:** Getting closer to the cause of the problem. The reason that events weren't getting logged in LoginActivity was because I was using a reserved event name: user event names cannot start with "google". After fixing that, events did start getting logged, including an ApiException "10:" when trying to log into a Google account. So I googled around and I THINK the bottom line is that when I opted into Google App Signing I may have uploaded the wrong app signing key. If that's the case, how do I upload the correct one? I hope the answer isn't "create a new app with a different package name and start over".

Answer (score 0):

After opting in to App Signing, I neglected to copy the SHA-1 fingerprint into my Firebase settings. Also, I needed to rebuild the app with the updated google-services.json. After doing all that and updating the release, the opt-in link worked fine.